# Backup MySQL via php, in a Symfony application

Tags: mysql, symfony1, backup, database-backups

I'm trying to do a php script to backup my database.
Here's what I've tried so far :

```
$command = "mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [databasename] | gzip > db.sql.gz";
$this->output = system($command);
```

- How do I get the password and
  username from *databases.yml* ?
- How can I do a script that sends me
  the backup file, instead of saving it
  on the server (à la phpmyadmin) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a symfony task. If you pass in an environment (i.e. dev, prod) or connection you get access to the Doctrine connection manager and create a connection. You can use that connection to make a database dump or get the connection details from the connection manager.

You can use the doctrine insert sql task as template for your task. I've done similar in the past.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I'd like to be able to do it from everywhere, without having to log in to the server via ssh

Comment: Your solution above will still require you to ssh into the server. The only way to do it without ssh'ing into the server is to trigger it from the browser. You can trigger symfony task from in side your action by instantiating the task class. This is exactly what the cli app does.

Comment: I'll look into doing that in the action

Comment: Yeah, any symfony cli task can be executed from an action. This has the added bonus of making your code reusable and testable.

Comment: What about the second part of my question, the sending of the file ?

Comment: Once you have the sql dump you can use symfony's mailer or use an scp wrapper. Phing has one in php. You define you email address or scp details in yiu app.yml config

Comment: The swift mailer is very easy to send emails and attach files in them. You just need the location of the sql dump. http://swiftmailer.org/docs/attaching-files